# How to display the same word in tkinter python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, python-3.9, tkinter-text

I am new in tkinter. I tried to code the program which display the same words in a window (with a txt file). I am trying but I can't do it. So I came here for asking.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from collections import Counter


main = Tk()
main.title(".TXT File Word Counter")
main.resizable(height=FALSE, width=FALSE)
main.geometry('500x400')
main.configure(bg='#757575')

labelfont = ("Arial", 14, "bold")

result = dict()

def clear_text():
    textfield.delete(0, END)
    ShowCountedWords.delete(1.0, END)

def open_file():
    main.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def count_word(file): #here is where I stuck
    with open(file) as f:
         print(Counter(f.read().split()))


heading = Label(main, text=".TXT File Word Counter")
heading.place(x=150, y=2)
heading.config(bg="#757575", font=labelfont, fg="#ffffff")

textfield = Entry()
textfield.place(x=3, y=30)
textfield.config(width=81, borderwidth=2)

btnSelectFile = Button(main, text="Select .txt File", command=lambda : open_file())
btnSelectFile.place(x=4, y=60)
btnSelectFile.config(width=20, bg="#66BB6A")

btnCount = Button(main, text="Count Words", command=lambda : count_word(main.filename))
btnCount.place(x=173, y=60)
btnCount.config(width=20, bg="#42A5F5")

btnClear = Button(main, text="Clear", command=lambda : clear_text())
btnClear.place(x=344, y=60)
btnClear.config(width=20, bg="#ef5350")

ShowCountedWords = Text(main, height=18, width=61)
ShowCountedWords.place(x=4, y=100)
ShowCountedWords.config(bg="#616161", fg="#ffffff")


main.mainloop()
```

the count_word function is working in console. I tried with that:

```
print(count_word("randomfilename.txt"))
```

Can you help me please? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Button callbacks shouldn't return anything, its pointless. Something like `print(Counter(f.read().split()))`, instead of returning it should work. Also what do you plan to do with this words after getting it?

Comment: Okay I'm going to edit my code as you said. My purpose is coding a count the same words in a text file and display these words in the tkinter window. For example: there is three "apple" in the text file. I want to display like this  in the tkinter window: 'apple': 3.

Comment: what you need to do is, once you read the file inside the function `count_word`, then you can iterate (loop) through the words in the file and add its counter in a dict or something. Once the dict is fully formed, you need to create `Label` with values as simple strings formed from that final dictionary.

Comment: I understand what I should do. Firstly I should use for loop for iterate then I should create an empty dict for the words. Finally I should write a label for this final dict. Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Text` here ?

Comment: surrealduck, that's right. @CoolCloud I guess he wishes to write the finalized values inside the Text widget.